# Solving simple parallel/series without Req

Tags: circuit-analysis, ohms-law, kirchhoffs-laws, equation

Given the following circuit with three resistors, R1=100Ω, R2=200Ω, R3=300Ω:

[image: ![enter image description here]

To solve this using the \$R_{eq}\$ trick:

```
R_eq = 1/(1/200 + 1/300) =  120 
5V = (100 + 120) * I
I = 5/220 = 0.0227A
```

How would I do this verbosely, creating all the systems of equations using Ohms/Kirchoffs laws to solve for this? I don't necessarily care about the actual solving of it, but more about setting up all the equations from each of the various series/parallel nodes.

Comment: One question......... why?

Comment: @Andyaka to learn / so I can understand how it works and what equations are involved in setting it up.

Comment: As mentioned in one of my comments to your previous posts, please point your earth symbols towards the Earth. It's distressing me. The symbol represents metal plates buried in the ground, not in the wall. Also, you should number your components R1, R2, etc., so we can reference them in our answers and equations.

Comment: @Transistor -- thanks. Updated.

Comment: looks the voltage source fell over on it's side

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try and answer my own question, hopefully I'm getting the gist of this.

Let's identify the current that flows through **R\$_{1}\$**, **R\$_{2}\$**, and **R\$_{3}\$** as **I\$_{1}\$**, **I\$_{2}\$**, and **I\$_{3}\$**, respectively. We know by Kirchoff's [current law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) that current flowing into a node = current flowing out of it, or:

\begin{equation*}
I_{1} = I_{2} + I_{3}
\end{equation*}

Next, from Kirchoff's [voltage law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we know that the sum of voltages across any closed path is zero. This gives us two equations for each possible path the circuit has:

\begin{equation*}
5 - V_{1} - V_{2} = 0
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
5 - V_{1} - V_{3} = 0
\end{equation*}

And substituting with [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) (*V = IR*) to solve for current, which we already have in the first equation, we get:

\begin{equation*}
5 - 100I_{1} - 200I_{2} = 0
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
5 - 100I_{1} - 300I_{3} = 0
\end{equation*}

This gives us three equations for three unknowns:

\begin{equation*}
I_{1} - I_{2} - I_{3} = 0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
100I_{1}\ + 200I_{2} = 5
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
100I_{1}\ + 300I_{3} = 5
\end{equation*}

We can convert this to a matrix and solve by getting its inverse:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1 \\
100 & 200 & 0 \\
100 & 0 & 300
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{1} \\
I_{2} \\
I_{3}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
5 \\
5
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{1} \\
I_{2} \\
I_{3}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.545 & 0.003 & 0.002 \\
-0.272 & 0.004 & -0.001 \\
0.182 & 0.001 & 0.003
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
5 \\
5
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Finally we get the currents for **I**:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
I_{1} \\
I_{2} \\
I_{3}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0.0227 \\
0.0136 \\
0.0090
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Which is what you get at the top using \$R_{eq}\$, of **0.0227A**.

Comment: How can I2 = I3 if R2 is not equal to R3?

Comment: @G36 they're not -- it's rounding. I can later update it so it has the full decimal, maybe to ten places or so.

Comment: @G36 updated with more precise decimals.

Comment: You haven’t specified the directions of the currents.

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple circuit the method you used is an overkill.

You can for exampel start by faiding \$R_{EQ} = R_1 + \frac{R_2 * R_3}{R_2 + R_3} = 100\Omega+ 120 \Omega\$ And solve for \$I_1\$:

\$I_1 = \frac{5V}{220\Omega} \approx 22.727\textrm{mA}\$

And next, we can use a current divider rule and find \$I_2\$ and \$I_3\$

\$I2 = I_1 \times \frac{R_3}{R_2 + R_3} \approx 13.636\textrm{mA} \$

\$I3 = I_1 \times \frac{R_2}{R_2 + R_3} \approx 9.09\textrm{mA} \$

Or we could use a voltage divider rule between \$R_1\$ and parallel connected \$R_2||R_3 = 120\Omega\$ and find the voltage across \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$:

\$V = 5V \times \frac{120\Omega}{100\Omega+ 120 \Omega} \approx 2.727V\$

And by knowing this voltage we can find all the currents in the circuit.

Comment: Right, but even the above is using Req, which I was trying to understand how to figure things out without using that. Also, where do you learn about the "voltage divider rule" or "current divider rule"?

Comment: It was a very long time ago when I learned about "voltage divider"  and about "current divider".  But you can try here https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-6/voltage-divider-circuits/ and here https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-6/current-divider-circuits/

Comment: got it. Thank you.